# Unable to open connection using some connection string

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I am using Sqlite database to save my data. It has no issue with normal connection strings, But when I am trying this connection string

```
"Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌ\CM.db;Version=3;New=false;"
```

it gives me error

> "unable to open connection"

I think this is unicode characters issue. If any one know this please take me oot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use @ before the connection string or escape the \ characters. Like @"Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌ\CM.db;Version=3;New=false;"

Comment: Thanks for replying. this is I have already tried. Actual connection string like this "Data Source=C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\ÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌ\\CM.db;Version‌​=3;New=false;"

Answer (score 0):

You have change your connection string into either

```
@"Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌ\CM.db;Version=3;New=false;"
```

or

```
"Data Source=C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\ÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌÄÇËìÕÆÉËÌ\\CM.db;Version=3;New=false;"
```

in quotes C# doesn't recognize '\' as an character.